# Disable/enable OAuth2 without two security configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a Spring Boot application that uses OAuth2 to realize SSO.
 Right now I'm using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation on my security configuration to disable OAuth2 when needed:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("some.property")
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER-3)
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfigurationOAuth2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

I also have a second security configuration that is beeing used when OAuth is disabled:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER-2)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

So far this is working but I don't like having two almost identical configurations. The only thing that needs to be disabled/enabled by a property is the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation. 

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If it really is only the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation that has to be enabled/disabled, is there any reason you can't just create another configuration which only has that annotation plus a @ConditionalOnProperty or @Profile?

Although not tested, you may be able to have a nested configuration class that is strictly meant for the conditional annotation like this:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER-3)
public class SecurityConfigurationOAuth2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Configuration
  @ConditionalOnProperty("some.property")  // Or use a profile
  @EnableOAuth2Sso
  static class EnableSSOConfig {
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is just the @EnableAuth2Sso annotation. This is basically what I'm doing right now, I'm sorry if my main post didn't convey this to you. The thing is I don't want to use two configurations because the HttpSecurity-object has to be maintained in both and is quite extensive.

Comment: I'm not suggesting having two almost identical configurations.  I'm suggesting having one main configuration which is always loaded and then another one specifically for the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation that is conditional.  
My code example is just giving you an option where you could keep the conditional annotation in your security config class just to keep things organized.